# How to insert two file.txt into one file

Tags: python-2.7

I have this function that takes two input .txt file, delete the punctuation mark, and adds the sentence pos or neg.
I would like the content of these fle converted to lowercase
and then these two files merged into a single file name union.txt
But my code does not work

```
def extractor (feature_select):
    posFeatures = []
    negFeatures = []

with open('positive.txt', 'r') as posSentences:
    for i in posSentences:
        posWords = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[(,.;:*@#/?!$&)]", i.rstrip())
        posWords = [feature_select(posWords), 'pos']
        posFeatures.append(posWords)
with open('negative.txt', 'r') as negSentences:
    for i in negSentences:
        negWords = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[(,.;:*@#/?!$&)]", i.rstrip())
        negWords = [feature_select(negWords), 'neg']
        negFeatures.append(negWords)

return posFeature, negFeature


filenames = [posFeature, negFeature]
with open('union.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to open the files with names from the contents of the two files. fname holds the contents read from the input files.

```
filenames = [posFeature, negFeature]
with open('union.txt', 'w') as outfile :
    for i in filenames :    #refers to posFeature or negFeature which is a list
        for j in i:    #this loop reads each sentence from the list i
            outfile.write(j) #it writes the sentence into outfile
```

No need to read back the contents already read and appended in posFeature and negFeature. Above code will directly write the contents in the list filenames and now your two files are merged.